# AjaxControlToolkit version that is compatible with System.web.extension 3.5.0.0

Tags: .net, ajax, frameworks

I was currently upgrading my application from VS 2008 to VS 2010 and in order to use the report viewer version 10.0 I need to change my system.web.extension from version 1.0.61025.0 to version 3.5.0.0 .

However, this move later break my Ajax control as it seems that my AjaxControlToolkit version 1.0.10301.0 requires System.web.extension version 1.0.61025.0 which I have removed from the bin folder. below is the error message

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I have been spending hours looking around  for a solution to this as in changing my ajaxcontroltoolkit version to other version but unable to find any information.

Most information that I found require me to change the system.web.extension reference back to 1.061025.0 which is not applicable in my situation.

**Update**: Change the ajaxcontroltoolkit to version 3.5 and remove the old ajaxcontroltoolkit 1.0.3 from bin folder and it works perfectly now.

Any helps or insight to this will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Is this library still alive? ;)

Comment: Which library do you mean? Not quiet sure with your question.

Comment: Ajax Control Toolkit library. I was more or less joking because it seems very odd to me that developers still use it. Or even implementing good old Ajax using update panels. I can only see benefits on legacy apps that need to be supported and upgraded as in your case for one reason or the other.

Comment: It is a legacy system and there is not much I can do to change it as a lot of functionality depends on the library. any ideas or workaround I can implement?